# Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?

Tags: grub2, uefi, external-hdd

It looks like [installing Ubuntu to an external harddrive](https://askubuntu.com/a/54388/40581) isn't possible with UEFI, where as with MBR there wasn't a big difference between external and internal. Is that true or is it still possible?

Is it even possible to combine both boot methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It actually **is possible**.

Before I continue, these instructions are meant for blank EFI System Partitions (ESP) and will probably overwrite existing files, or not work as expected. At least make backups!

## Adding required partitions for different  platforms

Platforms: Legacy PC, UEFI-based Windows computer, Apple computer

### Add an ESP to an existing installation with MBR

You need to follow these instructions from another installation or live media.

1. Install the `grub-efi-amd64-bin` package. This will only install the resources needed. It will not switch your existing MBR style installation to UEFI and turn things upside down.
2. Shrink your Ubuntu partition in [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to make space for an ESP. Recommended sizes for ESPs range from 100 MB to 500 MB, but the files created by following these instructions here will not require more than 2 to 5 megabytes.

   > Note: It shouldn't matter where your ESP is located on the disk and shrinking your Ubuntu partition by a few megabytes from the *end* should be quick and safe. Shrinking at the beginning is **not safe**. One caveat though, your ESP should be a primary partition and not be part of an extended partition or a logical volume, partition numbers from 1 to 4 are fine, numbers above indicate an extended partition on MBR partition tables.

   Choose FAT32 as filesystem and set the boot flag.
3. Mount the ESP you just created and the root filesystem you shrunk:

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt/esp
   mount $esp_device /mnt/esp
   mkdir -p /mnt/rootfs
   mount $root_device /mnt/rootfs
   ```

   > Note: Replace `$esp_device` and `$root_device` with the **appropriate devices** e.g. `/dev/sdb2` and `/dev/sdb1`. The **mountpoints** `/mnt/esp` and `/mnt/rootfs` are just examples chosen to work with the remaining part of this answer.

   Install GRUB's EFI image and a minimal configuration file with:

   ```
   grub-install --efi-directory /mnt/esp --boot-directory /mnt/rootfs/boot --target x86_64-efi --removable $device
   ```

   > Note that `$device` is the whole device e.g. `/dev/sdb`, not a partition.
4. That's it, we are already done, but let me try to explain a few things.

   The parameter `--target x86_64-efi` will ensure that UEFI images and modules will be installed to the given paths. `--removable` will install the UEFI image to the hardcoded path `\EFI\BOOT\BOOT{arch}.EFI` for removable media, instead of a distribution specific path. Your `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub/` should work with both boot methods and a new folder named `x86_64-efi` should now exist next to `i386-pc`.

   For completeness, this is the command for non-removable media which writes and relies on NVRAM entries in the platform:

   ```
   grub-install --efi-directory /mnt/esp --boot-directory /mnt/rootfs/boot --target x86_64-efi --bootloader-id "Ubuntu" $device
   ```

   Proper UEFI installations include a line similar to the one below in `/etc/fstab`, but the setup is functional without and the UEFI image (similar to the MBR bootloader) is usually only written/updated during OS installation.

   ```
   UUID=1234-567F /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
   ```

### Adding an ESP or GRUB-BBP to an installation with GPT

Adding an **ESP** to a legacy installation on a GPT partitioned drive is very similar to the above:

1. Install the `grub-efi-amd64-bin` package.
2. Create a partition with a FAT32 filesystem similar to the instructions above by resizing the root partition and set the `boot` flag.
3. Mount the partitions and run the `grub-install` command from above that includes the `--removable` parameter.

This also works if you just want to boot your exisitng UEFI installation on another computer.

Creating a **BIOS Bootable Partition** (BBP) for GRUB is a bit different:

1. Install the `grub-pc-bin` package.
2. Create a partition similar to the instructions above by resizing the root partition and set the `bios_grub` flag. Choose **no filesystem** and leave it unformatted.
3. Edit the configuration file `/etc/default/grub` with administrative rights and add `GRUB_DEVICE=/dev/sdb6` to the end. Replace `/dev/sdb6` with the actual device name of your BBP. You can use the commandline editor [nano](https://askubuntu.com/q/54221/40581) to keep thing a simple.

   Install the GRUB MBR image to the BBP with:

   ```
   grub-install --boot-directory /mnt/test/boot/ --target i386-pc $device
   ```

   You might want to remove or comment out the line in `/etc/default/grub` and add it to the actual installation.

### Bonus: Add a partition for Macs on an installation with GPT

I found that the very new Mac (Mac Mini A1347 EMC 2840) I was testing with could boot from a standard FAT32 ESP, even from MBR! Anyways, here we go:

1. Install the `grub-efi-amd64-bin`, `hfsprogs`, `mactel-boot` and `mactel-boot-logo` (optional) packages. You need to enable the *Universe* repositories ([How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/78613/40581)) and add the current [Mactel support PPA](https://launchpad.net/~detly/+archive/ubuntu/mactel-utils) (see [Mactel Support Community team](https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support-community) for more details) to install all of them.
2. Create a partition with an HFS+ filesystem similar to the instructions above by resizing the root partition. This time we need a few megabytes more space, so double the size of the ESP if you had only 5 megabytes or less before. No flag is required.
3. Mount the partitions:

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt/esp-mac
   mount $esp-mac_device /mnt/esp-mac
   mkdir -p /mnt/rootfs
   mount $root_device /mnt/rootfs
   ```

   > Note: I chose `$esp-mac_device` and `/mnt/esp-mac`to avoid conflicts.

   Run the `grub-install` command that includes the `--removable` parameter:

   ```
   grub-install --efi-directory /mnt/esp-mac --boot-directory /mnt/rootfs/boot --target x86_64-efi --removable $device
   ```

   Finally setup up the partition the way a Mac expects it to be:

   ```
   sudo hfs-bless /mnt/esp-mac/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi
   sudo cp -v /mnt/esp-mac/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi /mnt/esp-mac/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
   sudo cp -v /mnt/esp-mac/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg /mnt/esp-mac/System/Library/CoreServices/grub.cfg
   sudo cp -v /usr/share/mactel-boot/SystemVersion.plist /mnt/esp-mac/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
   sudo cp -v /usr/share/mactel-boot-logo/ubuntu.icns /mnt/esp-mac/.VolumeIcon.icns
   echo "Dummy kernel for booting" | sudo tee /mnt/esp-mac/mach_kernel
   ```

   To boot Ubuntu from external media on a Mac you would now just need to press the *option key* <kbd>⌥</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Windows keyboards and select the right disk.

   [image: Mac Startup Manager showing volumes and Ubuntu logo]

## About partition flags, type codes and GUIDs

To be as accurate as possible, the boot flag isn't important to GRUB, by default GRUB searches for UUIDs to find the right filesystem to boot from. Setting the boot flag or the bios_grub flag in GParted usually sets a type (MBR) or GUID (GPT) for the partition.

The benefit of setting the correct type or GUID, besides having a properly working setup, is that these partitions will be hidden in the filemanager. The easiest way to check and change types and GUIDs is via [Disks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) (`gnome-disks`).

[image: screenshot showing drives and partitions in gnome-disks]

[image: screenshot showing edit partition dialog in gnome-disks]

Alternatively you could use parted or gdisk:

- 0xef is the type code for ESP in MBR for use with fdisk
- ef00 is the abbreviated type code for ESP in GPT for use with gdisk
- ef02 is the abbreviated type code for BBP in GPT for use with gdisk

Wikipedia has a big list of [GUIDs for GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).

Commandline equivalents in `parted` according to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/set.html) are `parted $device set partition esp on` and `parted $device set partition bios_grub on`.

Comment: I did not document details. But was able to just partition my flash drive to gpt, create an efi partition and copy efi boot files into efi partition. The grub-mkimage creates a grubx64.efi that expects certain paths for files, so I just copied file structure from my install into a /boot/grub and added a grub.cfg with a configfile entry to another grub.cfg in my /iso folder to loopmount boot my ISOs. Probably more correct to create your own grubx64.efi with the make image, but copy worked.

Comment: I searched high and low trying to figure out how to do the "Add an ESP to an existing installation with MBR" part. I was nervous about it, but it worked on the first try! Great answer!

Comment: I am trying to add EFI boot capability to a full BIOS/MRR install of Ubuntu on USB using the **Add an ESP to an existing installation with MBR** part of the answer. I get a "Error: File `/boot/` not found". The `grub.cfg` in the ESP partition points to the right UUID. Any ideas? I would be happy to post a new question.

Comment: @user68186 were you able to do it?

Comment: I was able to install Ubuntu in my external drive from a Mac. When connected to the Mac it does boot correctly into Ubuntu. However, when connected to a Windows10 machine (xps 15 9560) in the boot devices the external hard drive does not appear. My hunch is that is due to the UEFI. Can someone confirm if my hunch is right and also if this thread is what I might need to be able to boot from a windows machine?