# Dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu on last partition with legacy boot mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 14.10

I have following scenario and want to install Ubuntu 14.10.

```
1 TB Hard Drive 
 150GB Win 8.1 Partition 
 200GB NTFS 
 200GB NTFS
 200GB NTFS 
 120GB NTFS 
 68GB Unallocated
```

I want to install Ubuntu 14.10 as dual boot with Windows 8.1 on 68GB partition. Can anyone let me know process and step need to be take care for this?

I have fresh installation of Windows 8.1 so no need for data backup.

**Note : I have installed Win 8.1 on Legacy Boot mode. So I think I have to install Ubuntu in Legacy mode as well.**

Comment: I want to install it in legacy mode and I don't want to change boot mode.

Comment: You still need to make sure fast boot or always on hibernation is off. And since you know which partition use something else. I hope you created partitions with extended and logical. Otherwise Windows converts to SFS or dynamic partitions which does not work with Linux.http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using

Comment: In addition to Eric Carvalho and oldfred, if you have a plain GPT partitioned disk Ubuntu should be able to detect this and set things like a GRUB BIOS Boot Partition up automatically. Otherwise you can find instructions for a GRUB BBP in http://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581

Answer (score 0):

Even I want help for the same issue.I want to install ubuntu on unallocated  free space while I have windows 8.1 installed in legacy mode.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this should ahve been added as a comment and not an answer as you are not adding to the question.  A comment can be used to subscribe to something

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 comes pre-installed in UEFI mode by default. Anyway, it's not that important.   Lets make it a dual-boot in Legacy mode itself.
Step 1:
Get a (minimum)4GB pendrive and download Linux Ubuntu in your system. Now, download   Universal USB Installer from the internet. Run that software and install your Ubuntu on the pendrive.
Step 2: After doing this step, note down all the drives that you have on your Windows OS with their allocated memory sizes and used capacity.
Do this much, and let me know.
Link for USB Installer: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/