# Install on HP 110-210 - Error: No Media Present

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, livedvd

I have just purchased an HP 110-210 Desktop PC that came with Windows installed on its 500GB disk.   I loaded an Ubuntu 14.04.1 DVD and installed Ubuntu, replacing Windows.

Following installation and following the removal of the install DVD, Ubuntu will not boot.  The following messages occur:

```
Checking Media Presence
No Media Present
```

I repeated the installation with the same result.

Comment: That's actually an issue I ran into already, and it turns out that there's some "signature verification" going on, making it near-impossible to install Ubuntu onto a new PC. Even bypassing the signature thing flubs, as the new EFI stuff makes things into a nightmare. I wouldn't know what to suggest, but at least you know a little more about your problem. =P

Comment: Additional thing I found while lurking around, worth a read: [Installing Ubuntu on UEFI-supported devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
You may end up needing to get Windows 8 back on your system.

Comment: @Omio Instead of making it look like rocket science and viciousness, expect incompetence and patronizing. The manufacturer doesn't expect you to install any other operating system than Windows and no consumer stood in and spoke up. Please don't assume some "`"signature verification"`" being in place unless you did sophisticated reverse engineering [like this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BrdX7VdOr0) and actually found a mechanism like that.

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve this kind of issue personally, so I _only_ have second-hand info to go by. Also, I believe that's what `SecureBoot` was all about.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter BIOS settings and set your HDD as a primary boot device.
Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> key almost immediately after Power-on then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to enter BIOS utility. (the hotkeys are especially valid for HP hardware, different manufacturers' computers may have other keyboard shortcuts to enter BIOS)

Answer (score 1):

I think *aFoP* is right in suggesting to set the HDD as primary boot device. You may have removed Windows from the harddrive but in the UEFI firmware settings it may still be configured to boot the Windows OS in UEFI mode that is no more.

If you [followed the how-to correctly and installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/40581) on this new machine it usually creates an `ubuntu` boot entry and sets it as the primary boot option, but HP UEFI firmwares have sort of "ignored" this in the past (accepting the command and creating the entry but…) after rebooting they still expected to boot Windows.

For UEFI-installations disabling any *Fast Boot* option¹ in the firmware setting, optionally disabling *Secure Boot* and installing the bootloader with the *`--removable`* [option](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581) to boot from the HDD/SSD should give you a booting OS.

For MBR-installations just disabling UEFI and booting from the HDD/SSD should work as aFoP described.

¹ Apparently managing the boot order to have your favorite OS in first position, detecting drives (disabling slow drives like FDDs, ODDs, big HDDs) and operating systems was so hard that this switch had to be invented, which boots nothing else than Windows and saves a few nanoseconds over a properly configured setup that boots Linux.