# Enter BIOS from Ubuntu 14.04 (Ideapad Yoga 13 - Novo Button)

Tags: boot, wireless, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I changed the BIOS settings in my Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga13 running Windows 8.1, as I was having difficulties in installing Ubuntu 14.04. In the process I also changed the UEFI to LEGACY. Later Ubuntu booted up and installed from a USB stick. But I cannot access Windows, even with a recovery stick I had made earlier. It looks like my mistake has locked me out of Windows.

I have been trying to get into BIOS to reset back to UEFI from LEGACY. But F2, F10, F12, all fail to get me into BIOS. I need help in getting into BIOS from Ubuntu. If command line is an option, please give me the appropriate commands step by step. I am a newbie to all this with little or no understanding of how these things work, so clear step-by-step advice is required. Did I tell you that Ubuntu doesn't connect to WiFi and I have to use a USB dongle to connect to the internet? I need advice on that too, please.

Thanks Guys. The Lenovo button worked and I got Windows 8.1 and WiFi back, but the bad news is I have lost Ubuntu! When I boot, the GRUB menu with Ubuntu and Windows options does not appear anymore. In order to get Windows back, I reset the BIOS boot option from LEGACY back to UEFI. Now I cannot get into Ubuntu! Any thoughts?

Comment: Of course you cannot boot a non-UEFI installed OS in UEFI mode. [Add an ESP to an existing installation with MBR](http://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: As for WiFi you should ask another question after looking for similar questions and hardware (WiFi chips).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual](https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/yoga13_ug_en.pdf), you enter the BIOS with the Novo button. Please see here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press shift while booting the laptop and hold it until the grub menu appears, then see if system settings is an option in grub as it should get you into BIOS but may not be available in Legacy mode.  It works on my Lenovo Ideapad G710 in UEFI

Comment: Thanks guysNow the GRUB menu appears when I boot in and is able to load Ubuntu. When I choose the Windows options - load or recovery - Win does not load. The screen says "unable to boot Windows. Some setting have have been changed". However if I access Bios through the Novo button and change Bios settings to UEFI and then boot, I am able to boot into Windows, but no sign of Ubuntu anywhere; but I have WiFi connection!. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your wifi is likely hard blocked, check with `rfkill list all` and usually you need to `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and `sudo rfkill unblock all` to enable

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31. I did that. Wifi is neither soft nor hard blocked. But still the wifi does not work! Any other solution?