# full Lubuntu installation on USB (UEFI capable)

Tags: boot, lubuntu, uefi

I want to do a full Lubuntu installation on a USB stick that can be booted in UEFI mode.

I do not want persistent Live USB but a full Lubuntu installation (which happens to live on a USB stick) and that can boot from **any** UEFI-capable computer...

Comment: Hello and welcome on AskUbuntu. Could you please clarify what you want? I don't understand you very well, as for me it sounds like a persistent live USB...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. I don't want a persistent live USB, I want a full installation on a USB drive that boots from UEFI. 

I managed to do a full installation of Lubuntu on a USB, but it can only boot in MBR mode. I would like to do the same but booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I don't have a good knowledge of UEFI. This is up to someone else... :(

Comment: Thanks for the effort though :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same as any install to a second drive. And you do want an efi partition on the flash drive and grub installed to that drive.

But when I installed a second Ubuntu to my HDD, it overwrote the efi partition on my SSD. So backup main drive's efi partition. You can then just copy efi partition from main drive to flash drive if it still overwrites. I am sure I did select to install grub to my sdb drive in Something Else install.

Create efi partition with gpt partitioning on flash drive drive first.

[Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi)

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: Good one! (so upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

There is a walk through of installation of Ubuntu in EFI mode on the Community WIKI.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_EFI_mode
I could not find anything on installing to a flash drive but it would seem that the principle should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's quite late for a reply but I'll try. The standard installer is buggy when it comes to USB flash drive installation and it writes the new UEFI configuration files to the HDD, breaking also the HDD installation. Luckily, the HDD installation can be easily restored with boot-repair.
A full installation to flash drive is possible, though, if you manually do part of that which the installer was supposed to: that is, if you manually make an EFI partition in your flash drive, if you produce a new grub.cfg and if you copy to the EFI partition several files that are already in your /boot/efi directory. You can find the complete procedure [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836). It looks much longer than it actually is because every step is described in detail. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the link! For me it is a while ago that I worked on this. I will however have to work with in in the near future, so the information provided will be very useful. With regards to the link, as far as I have seen, the information is very structured and well explained. Thanks again for your input.