# Writing x64 Ubuntu on USB from the same USB

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

**The goal is** to create a bootable USB flash, install Ubuntu 16.04 STL x64 on itself.

---

I have downloaded x32 version first from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/. Used https://rufus.akeo.ie/ to create a bootable USB flash - selected DD, since there were problems with ISO and cdrom not found. The partition then look like:

[image]

During the partition step of the installation I was prompted with:

[image]

Which allowed me to select 14GB unlocated space and the system was installed into it and installation went fine and everything was great!

---

Now when trying to do the exact same procedure but with the http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso, the Rufus would suddenly break partitions in the other wasy:

[image]

During the installation I was never prompted to select allocated space. Instead it used the entire disc in the middle of installation - breaking everything and unable to finish.

Now does anyone knows how to make this work?
- Either partition x64 distro in a correct manner?
- Partition things manually?

UnetBooting didn't work either - the ISO wouldn't even be cathed by the system.

Comment: Have a look see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Answer (score 0):

After spending 5 hours on this, trying up to dozen solution I ended up bringing 2nd empty 16GB USB drive and installed on it (while using 1st USB drive as an installer).