# Installing Ubuntu from USB problem

Tags: usb, live-usb

I'm new to all of this and I'm having trouble installing the OS. I've made the boot drive for the USB and was able to boot it from there. The problem is that when I use either "try ubuntu without installing" or "install ubuntu" the loading screen starts for about 10 seconds and the loading bar stops.

I've tried letting it do its thing overnight but still no progress.
Also, another question: would I be able to install the OS onto the boot drive or does it have to be installed on a separate drive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you format the bootable USB right. If your computer is UEFI, then you should choose partition scheme `GPT for UEFI`. Use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make it right.

Comment: You can install to the drive it was booted from by booting to RAM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Answer (score 0):

The loading bar stops probably due to some error while starting up ubuntu, you can try press Esc to see if you can switch back to the console mode (text display which shows what is exactly running). If Esc is not working then try ctl+alt+F1 (I am not very sure but you can try F1 to F7 to see if you can switch to console mode). Once you get to the console mode you will be able to see what is causing the freezing of the progress bar.

As for the installation of OS, are you saying you are trying to install ubuntu onto the usb drive you used to boot? That is possible but required some extra work when creating the ubuntu boot drive, because normally when the usb boot drive was created, it was created as a single disk partition and this way the installer will not allow you to install on the boot drive.

Comment: Using ctrl + alt + f2 worked. I'm getting this code: "tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfed40080-0xfed40fff]"

Comment: Oh and yes. I've partitioned a part of the USB just for the boot and left the rest unallocated in hopes that I can allocate it during the install.