# Making a persistent bootable USB drive error

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I am trying to explore Linux by making a persistent USB drive with Ubuntu. I have followed a few guides but nothing works. So far I've tried (using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Windows 7/10):

1. Using lili USB live creator to make a persistent drive. It boots just fine, but the persistence does not work...
2. Using unetbootin with the same results

Any thoughts?

Another thing I could try is to do a full installation on the USB drive, the problem is that I only have on USB drive...¨

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Persistence works. This site is littered with dozens of "I cannot get persistence to work," questions, but it DOES work...if you follow the instructions carefully. Those other questions, when enough information was provided, turned out to be folks who skipped steps or misread the instructions or chose the wrong option or otherwise were not careful.

Comment: I'll go over to the guides to see if I missed anything

Comment: I am using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGthtXxW8nk

I am doing the same thing as him with the same version and it still doesn't work

Comment: Only one pendrive? No problem: **Install Full Ubuntu to the Live pendrive it was booted from**  https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Comment: Please try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It works in Ubuntu and can clone to create a live-only system and **create a persistent live system with a `casper-rw` partition**, so that you can use the whole USB drive (not limited to 4 GiB).