# UnetBootIn BootLoader Error

Tags: bootloader, 18.10, unetbootin

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 as a dual boot option along with my Windows 10. I dont have a flash drive on me right now. And I think DVD drive doesn't work. So I Googled a bit and found UnetBootIn tool. So I created a boot option on my C drive and then rebooted, and when I select UNetBootIn option on the OS selection screen, I see an error saying file missing or contains error message.

```
File: \ubnldr.mbr
```

I have attached the screen shot of the error and also how I did the UNetBootIn thing.

Please tell me how to get over this hurdle.

[UNetBootIn Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWmLu.png)

Sorry, I am not able to show the image of the error as the file is too big, so I put a link in:
https://i592.photobucket.com/albums/tt7/sam20044/IMG_20190223_181727_zpssp4ep7sf.jpg

Comment: Is your Windows still working? I think the method you are using will overwrite your C drive including the Windows OS. Better to get a flash drive.

Comment: Yes it is. I got around it by partitioning a new drive of 4GB from the C drive and creating a bootable drive on that using LiLi. That seemed to work fine. I don't know if that is the correct solution to this problem, so I left it unanswered. I think the Windows partition and the Linux boot just confused the BIOS. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I think you can Fully install to a partition on your computer booting your Live version using toram see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Comment: Very clever! Please answer your own question here, a lot of people have asked how to install Ubuntu without a flash drive. You will get at least one up vote for sure.

Comment: +1. I agree with C.S.Cameron. *Please spend some time to answer your own question and describe with as many details and steps as possible what you did. I think it will be useful for many people.* (But I think that is is much safer and easier to use a USB pendrive for this purpose.)

Comment: If you guys want to know how he did this, he opened his disk manager, shrunk his main volume by 4 GB. Formatted it to Fat32 and then used LiLi usb creator to install Ubuntu onto it and booted to that volume