# How to install ubuntu on external HDD if I dont have flash drive or DVD?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, 19.04

I dont have dvd or flash drive (pendrive) and I am on windows 10 pro now.I want to install ubuntu 18.04 on my internal ssd, or atleast on my external hdd( which is the only thing that I have). Please help me install.Only thing that is stoping me from trying annything is that I dont have DVD or Pen drive.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus is unsupported, and off-topic on this site. I'd suggest installing a supported release of Ubuntu instead (and consider a LTS or *long-term-support* release) if you don't specifically need a specific version.

Comment: okay,but how to install??

Comment: Site rules say only supported releases (not development, EOL/ESM etc), and Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, but you're on your own, and cannot any longer use Canonical/Ubuntu infrastructure (this is an official Ubuntu site). https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  *You have your boot manager run the ISO*

Comment: Version typo has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin Frugal Install

You can use a UNetbootin Frugal Install, https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/,  to create a temporary Ubuntu Live install on the corner of your Windows hard disk. You can boot this frugal install and use it to install Ubuntu to unused space on the same hard disk.

In UNetbootin select Type: = Hard Disk. On the next boot after installing Ubuntu, you will be given the oppertunity to remove the frugal install completely.

[image]

Would suggest that you install Ubuntu 18.04 if you want a stable OS or you can give 20.04 a try. you would have a hard time with 19.04.

### UNetbootin Install to External HDD

As an alternate to the above solution you can create a small, 3GB FAT32 partition on the external drive and use UNetbootin to create an installer image in that.

To boot the external drive press `F2`, `F9`, `F12`, etc when booting and select the external drive. Press `shift` and a language screen should appear. press `ESC`, press `F6`, press `ESC` and type a space then type `toram`. press `F10` to boot.

Once booted you can run the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop.

For reference see: [Can Ubuntu be installed to the pendrive it was booted from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from)