# How to install using my internal hard drive?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I want to switch from windows to linux cause I heard its good for programming, But I dont have an external hard drive or usb I can use and cant use a disc cause no disc drive, Is there a way to install it with the hard drives in my computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You are limited to whatever devices your hardware will boot (be in cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-media/sd-card/..) or whatever boot loader you have installed (`grub` for example can boot a ISO file directly allowing you to install to a different partition to whatever the ISO is stored; or the same partition if fully loaded into RAM before execution). The standard windows boot loader doesn't provide many options (it primarily only boots itself).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install Ubuntu FROM a smartphone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277306/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-from-a-smartphone)

Comment: Please refer to ubuntu documentation

Comment: This is a near duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232357/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-external-hdd-if-i-dont-have-flash-drive-or-dvd

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin Frugal Install

You can use a UNetbootin Frugal Install, https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/,  to create a temporary Ubuntu Live install on the corner of your Windows hard disk. You can boot this frugal install and use it to install Ubuntu to unused space on the same hard disk.

In UNetbootin select Type: = Hard Disk. On the next boot after installing Ubuntu, you will be given the oppertunity to remove the frugal install completely.

[image]

I also managed to install Ubuntu using a cell phone: [Installing Ubuntu Using Cell Phone Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only)