# How to **single boot** **not dual boot** ubuntu linux without pendrive?

Tags: boot, usb-drive

How to single boot ubuntu linux without pendrive?

Because I don't have a pendrive. After installing windows 10 on my PC it has became very slow , and many of the softwares are not available for windows 32 bit.

Linux is so fast as compared to windows, and windows is using my 70% computer resources, there are many problems in windows.

Comment: Use a [DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Comment: I mean without any type of accessories  .

Comment: Remove harddisk with Windows and replace it with a spare one... Install and test Ubuntu on this new disk. You can always revert to Windows by switching the disk drive.

Comment: Now I'm going to work, but I think is possible. If it is, I'll write an answer later.

Comment: hello FedonKadifeli , can you give me another idea, how can i remove my harddisk :( , there is risk in doing

Comment: Is this a 32bit computer or can is it 64 bit?  You said windows 32 bit.  Ubuntu is getting out of 32 bit and if you need 32 bit OS, will need to find other Linuxs that still support it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Ubuntu without CD and USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb)

Comment: crip bro ,  i have 32 bit one , which linux distro should i install then , :( , bro kashish i want to single boot ubuntu ..

Comment: Ubuntu 32bit OSs will be out of support sometime next year.  Can see this link for other 32bit linux, but will have to check with them for how long support will last.  Also check if your CPU is only 32bit, or you are only using 32 bit windows on a 64bit computer.  https://fossbytes.com/best-lightweight-linux-distros/

Comment: crip659 , that's totally fine but please tell me **How do I Single boot ubuntu without pendrive or other accessories**

Comment: Shrink the windows partition as much as possible, use the link that kashish showed and then install ubuntu/linux on new partition.  Do not think any other way of doing it without a CD/DVD or USB.  Might be able to remove Windows after and use whole drive for Linux, but that will be another question.

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: You have windows now.  Need to shrink/make smaller the partition windows is on and make new partition for new Linux OS.

Comment: hey crip bro i dont have uefi , i have bios

Comment: First answer in link is for bios at top then UEFI at bottom.  Read whole question and answers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. How about a **Cell Phone**, I can install Ubuntu from my cell phone, or an **MP3 player**, I have Ubuntu live installed on my MP3 player, or a **Camera** I also installed Ubuntu on my camera's SD card. You used to be able to do a Frugal install using UNetbootin. Ubuntu is installed to a corner of your HDD and will boot to Ubuntu installer next time the computer is started. If your computer is old that might still work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250746/how-to-install-using-my-internal-hard-drive/1250798#1250798

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install Ubuntu, I suggest Xubuntu, which you could install from your .iso file using grb2win.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/

Grub2Win is completely free, open source software. All modules are digitally signed for your security.

Safely boot multiple Windows and Linux systems on both GPT and MBR disks.

Supports both 64 and 32 bit EFI firmware as well as BIOS. Installs to Windows 10, 8, 7 and XP.

Grub2Win boots native GNU Grub version 2.04 code. Everything is installed to a single 20 MB directory on your Windows C: drive. The install also copies five boot modules to your EFI partition.

Automatically generates config files for PhoenixOS, Android, Ubuntu, Debian, Suse, Fedora, Manjaro, Mint, Clover and Windows. You can import Linux config files for all other distributions.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin Frugal Installer

You can make a Frugal install of Ubuntu to your hard drive that can be used to make a Full install to it.

Full details are given on this page:

https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes

See: **Making a full, standard hard disk install if you can't use a Live USB**