# Can i make my bootable usb have a persistent storage after creating it without it?

Tags: live-usb

I created a bootable usb to live boot ubuntu but during setting it up i forgot to give it a persistent storage so that i can save my changes during boots , is there a way to do it without getting the usb back to normal state(unbootable) and re-creating a bootable usb with persistent storage?
please help!

Answer (score 0):

### Changing Live Pendrive to Persistent Pendrive

This works both with BIOS and UEFI.

Many people prefer a Persistent Pendrive that will save changes;

- Create a Live Pendrive using **Rufus** or similar;
- Boot the pendrive **toram** to make the drive editable:

  Press Shift when booting; press Esc from Language; press F6; press Esc;

  Type a Space and `toram` after `quiet splash ---`, and press Enter.
- Create a *casper-rw* file:

  `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512`

  `sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw`

(where `count=512` is the persistence size in megabytes, with a max of 4GB).

- Move the new *casper-rw* file from *home* to the *root* of the Live Pendrive;
- Add a Space and `persistent` after `quiet splash ---` in the following files:

  `/isolinux/txt.cfg`, (for BIOS boot persistence Rufus);

  `/syslinux.cfg`, (for BIOS boot persistence UNetbootin);

  `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, (for UEFI boot persistence).
- Shut down and reboot the persistent drive.

It's also possible to turn a Live USB into a Full-Install USB which has some advantages, except it won't install Ubuntu: [Can Ubuntu be installed to the pendrive it was booted from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from)