# Install Ubuntu on bootable USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I want to install a Ubuntu 18.04 environment on a USB. I only have one USB and can therefore not install the [ISO image from Ubuntu](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) on one USB and install it on the other USB (like done [here](https://itsfoss.com/intsall-ubuntu-on-usb/)).

I believe that the installer ISO for Desktop (found [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/)) can be used as a full Ubuntu environment, but it removes all the changes after a restart and does not store it on the USB itself. Is it possible to disable this and keep the changes on the USB? Or is there an IMG/ISO file for an Ubuntu environment that can directly be written to a USB and doesn't require installing first (from a reputable source)?

Comment: What operating system are you running now? Do you know about persistent live drives?

Comment: @sudodus I am now running dual boot (Linux Mint + Windows 11) but I don't want to change anything in the software of my PC, I want a standalone USB to run Ubuntu from using any PC. And I haven't heard of persistent live drives but it looks like that could solve the issue by creating persistent storage on the USB. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you can install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Linux Mint, and from there create a persistent live drive with Ubuntu. (I suggest that you try a newer version, 20.04.x LTS or 22.04 LTS instead of 18.04 LTS.)

Comment: Thanks! and I would've liked to use a newer version but I need 18.04 because of outdated software that requires it

Comment: I see. Good luck :-)

Comment: Ubuntu can be installed to the pendrive it was booted from, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from