# How can I convert Ubuntu to UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 in UEFI mode alongside windows 8, which is already in UEFI mode.

- My partition scheme is GPT.
- Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda5`.
- Legacy bootloader on `/dev/sda`.
- Windows on `/dev/sda4`.

UEFI bootloader in EFI partition

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can un-install grub-pc(BIOS) and install grub-efi-amd64(UEFI). Easiest to do with advanced options in Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: You can *Add an EFI system partition to an existing installation with MBR*, see my answer here:  http://askubuntu.com/a/559008/40581 for UEFI Secure Boot you need to install shim and linux-signed-image-generic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change/convert a  Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](/q/84501) – skip the part about converting the partition table. There's also [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](/q/509423) and [“Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode” in the community help](//help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'convert' Ubuntu to UEFI. It is already installed in UEFI mode, because the uefi bootloader uses an EFI partition (as well as Windows, too). In (old) BIOS mode there is no need for an EFI partition. Legacy bootloader seems to be kinda backup boot mode, in case efi bootloader got corrupted.

Comment: You can have Ubuntu in CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot mode on gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: I want to have UEFI grub2 instead of legancy grub2 is my question clearer

Comment: @ap4ss3rby: the name "legacy grub2" is a bit odd, because "legacy grub" usually refers to Grub 1.x (with x < 90, i. e. not Grub 2 or its pre-releases). A better term would be something like “Grub in legacy mode” as opposed to “UEFI mode”.