# Multi boot EFI and MBR/BIOS pendrive, one grub.cfg file

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm creating a bootable USB with grub bootloader. The goal is to realize something  with the highest possible compatibility both for BIOS and UEFI. So, first step, i normally installed grub bootloader for BIOS and copied a EFI bootloader compatible with both 32 and 64 bit EFI systems (copied the clonezilla one!). All boot-related files are in a ext4 partition.

Second step: the most important thing is that I want a unique `grub.cfg` file to edit instead of two (one for BIOS, other for EFI). My idea was to create two symbolic links with same target `grub.cfg` file. The idea worked well excpet for EFI Windows systems. That because they only support EFI bootable files in FAT32 partition, while I use an ext4 partition!

Now the problem: how to create something similar and equally useful in a FAT32 partition, which doesn't support symbolic links?

Comment: Some more info here: Flash drive to boot in UEFI or BIOS - sudodus
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS And:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Ubuntu_single_boot_in_UEFI_mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you actually did different and where your problem is, but may be we can figure it out.

Did you know that you can not only chainload other bootloaders like Windowx or OS X but other grub.cfg files?

```
search.fs_uuid 7bd6ae5a-b02b-4acf-b5f5-0d7c6b435d5b root hd0,gpt2
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

This code looks for the root filesystem with the specified UUID on the first hdd in the second partition. It sets a variable named prefix and finally boots grub.cfg from /boot/grub of the root filesystem. You may find this code in every FAT32 EFI system partition on Ubuntu. (The Fedora setup is ab bit different and stores kernels on the ESP and has a symlink of grub.cfg in /etc that links to the ESP IIRC, the Ubuntu configuration is as close to a symbolic link as possible in my opinion.) By default every grub EFI loader runs such a grub.cfg when no configuration is included into the the binary itself. (Yep, you may find a configuration file tacked to the end of the binary and some certificates if the binary is singed when you view the file in a hex editor.) So just modify this code to your needs that it loads the grub.cfg you want and place it on your ESP next to your bootx64.efi and bootia32.efi files. Package grub-efi-ia32-bin is available in Ubuntu 16.04 so you should be able to also install a 32-bit EFI loader. The only thing left is to configure the MBR loader.

- [Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581) — This is where I explain what I do to configure an external drive with Ubuntu to boot on the most common platforms it mostly deals with the `grub-install` command.
- [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581) — This a bit more advanced and explains how to generate your own grub images for different architectures with a custom list of modules like loopback and basic grub.cfg menu entries to boot ISOs for example.

What do you need to get your puzzle pieces together the way you want?

Comment: I think your answer could help me! Thanks. Let me try...

Comment: Wait..I have to boot that code in a menu entry,  didn't I?

Comment: No you don't have to create a menu, it's a very simple configuration for a grub.cfg to place next to your bootx64.efi grub image. But it depends on what your current setup looks like e.g. which file is where.