# Boot Xubuntu Installation from USB on EFI (MAC) & PC (NON EFI)

Tags: boot, xubuntu, uefi, mbr

- I have a full Xubuntu Installation on a USB Drive and configured it to boot on a MAC. It is recognized as "EFI  Boot".
- The Drive won't boot on a regular Laptop with  a Bios.

Is there a possibility to make this bootable via EFI and MBR?
Or may i rather use a Live Stick for this?
A Live Stick which i have tested will boot on both.

Comment: "BIOS" is an ambiguous term. Does the PC in question support EFI boot, or  only MBR booting?

Comment: Sorry,you are of course right. Its a non EFI Bios with MBR Booting.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that or not, but you could install it as MBR only and use an rEFInd DVD to boot it on your Mac.

Comment: On a Live Stick this seems to be possible. But i could not figure out how to set up this on an installation

Comment: @rod-smith: can you have a look here, please?

Comment: May the solution to add a bios_grub flagged partition and install grub bootmanager? Forgot to add that its a GPT formatted Stick. I think this is how the live cds do it.

Comment: Maybe i found the solution over her: https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi  There it is explained how to add a BIOS Bootable Partition (BBP) for GRUB. Is this what i am looking for?