# Beginners' questions: boot & removable media setup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, boot-repair

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an external USB flash drive (let's denote it by USB A). My computer is running windows 10, with a fairly new motherboard.
I did the following:
I prepared an installation media (a different USB flash drive, USB B) using Rufus. I have two options in BIOS, to either boot to USB A as UEFI or not. I booted as UEFI.
I created two partitions on USB A, one a swap with 8gb, and another one with ~56gb as ext4. I entered setup from Ubuntu, using "try Ubuntu" option.

As setup starts, I get a warning that BIOS mode operating system was detected, I choose force UEFI mode and continue with setup.
At some point, installation crashes with `grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/`. I tried to repair with boot-repair and get "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition” error.

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. I have searched the forums and while there has been many discussions on relevant topics, I didn't find the right answer (or maybe I didn't get it).

- Do I need to rerun Ubuntu setup?
- How do I avoid this error or fix it after setup is complete (assume the answer to A is no).
- Will running setup from a different computer work (the installation media is a usb drive, and the target media is also a usb drive)

Safe boot and fast boot are disabled.

Comment: You have to partition in advance with gpt partitioning if you want UEFI boot on external and have the ESP - efi system partition. Grub only installs to drive seen as sda as /EFI/ubuntu. And externals only boot with UEFI from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. So some manual coping & renaming required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred That is more of an answer than a comment. Please consider converting it to an answer.