# How can I install Ubuntu on a 2012 mac pro?

Tags: software-installation

I have a 2012 mac pro 5.1(tower) with 4 hard drive bays. I want to install ubuntu on a 2TB SSD in one of the bays. The 2TB drive is formatted FAT 32.
Currently it is set up to duel boot osX.11, or osx.12
it has a 3.33 Ghz 6 core processor with 32 GB
I have created a flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04, when I try to install, holding down “option” key, nothing happens.
Thanks
Creighton

Comment: hmm don't think we can answer this: seems a hardware problem. Figure out how to boot from an USB and if the live usb is created correctly. AskUbuntu is for questions regarding Ubuntu and you do not have that yet. You need at minimum the grub selection menu  from the installer for us to be able to help :)

Comment: Is drive gpt partitioned? Did you create an UEFI bootable flash drive. Some tools may create a BIOS only installer, most tools create one that is both UEFI & BIOS and then UEFI should work. iMac 13, 2 (late 2012) 27"  It Just Works! 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425170 Info on external or any second drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/559007/is-it-still-possible-to-install-ubuntu-to-an-external-harddrive-with-uefi

Comment: Try clearing the PRAM (Option+Command+P+R) during startup until it chimes, a few times in a row.  Then try pressing down and holding the option key to see if it gives you the boot menu.